# - [_ NSCFType encodeWithCode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281e86820

Tags: ios, iphone

My project encountered an occasional crash in versions of iOS 15.6.1 and above, and there were no issues with other versions. Crash message: `- [__NSCFType encodeWithCode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281e86820`  `-[__NSCFType initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2811c2e20`,

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:filePath];

id object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileName]
```

EncodeWithCoder and initWithCoder have been implemented.The code has been running for several years without any issues.
Has anyone encountered it or know the reason?

Comment: Both APIs are deprecated for a long time and implementing the *secure* APIs might give you a more specific error. Nevertheless the error is related to a CoreFoundation object, `NSCFType` in CoreFoundation is similar to `AnyObject` in Objective-C.

Comment: I plan to try using the new APIs to obtain more error information.